# Reshape factor levels to columns (no action on values)

Tags: r, reshape

I need some help reshaping my dataframe. I just want each level of my factor "Season" to become 2 new columns and the values come from the column "den" (no summing or averaging of values). This is probably a very easy task, but nothing I try seems to work.

```
df %>%
      group_by(Season) %>%
      mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = "Season", values_from = "den")

Error in `n()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.



spread(df, Season, den)

Error in `spread()`:
    ! Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.



reshape(data=df, timevar="Season",idvar="assem",direction="wide" )
                   assem   den.DRY   den.WET
1  Goldspotted Killifish 0.0000000 0.3333333
2                    Far 0.6666667 0.3333333
3                    Pal 0.0000000 1.3333333
4          Gulf Pipefish 0.0000000 0.0000000
18   Rainwater Killifish        NA 1.0000000
Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for Season=DRY: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for Season=WET: first taken
```

Update (form I'd like it to take):

```
assem                   WET    DRY
Goldspotted Killifish   NA     0.000
Goldspotted Killifish   NA     0.000
Goldspotted Killifish   NA     0.000
Goldspotted Killifish   NA     0.000
Goldspotted Killifish   NA     1.333
Goldspotted Killifish   0.333  NA
Goldspotted Killifish   2      NA
Goldspotted Killifish   0.333  NA
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("DRY", 
"WET"), class = "factor"), assem = c("Goldspotted Killifish", 
"Far", "Pal", "Gulf Pipefish", "Pal", "Goldspotted Killifish", 
"Far", "Goldspotted Killifish", "Goldspotted Killifish", "Goldspotted Killifish", 
"Far", "Goldspotted Killifish", "Pal", "Gulf Pipefish", "Far", 
"Goldspotted Killifish", "Pal", "Rainwater Killifish", "Rainwater Killifish", 
"Goldspotted Killifish"), den = c(0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.33333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
1.33333333333333, 0, 0, 2, 2.33333333333333, 1, 1.33333333333333, 
0.333333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your sample input you have 5 rows with `DRY` and `Goldspotted Killifish` and 3 rows with `WET` and `Goldspotted Killifish`. There's no indication in the data frame of *which* DRY value should be paired with each WET value (this is what your error is complaining about). So, how should this be handled? Should the pairing be in order - the first DRY value with the first WET value for each `assem` value? Or something else? What do we do when there are different numbers of observations in DRY and WET? Drop the extras? Fill with `NA`? Something else?

Comment: If you would show the exact output you want from this sample input and explain the answers to those questions, that would help a lot.

Comment: @GregorThomas Aha, I see. Unfortunately I'm not aware of how to create the form it should have in R, but this might help. den values only belong to a DRY or a WET, not both. So, if a value belongs to DRY, the WET value should be NA.

Comment: For example, in this new df row 1 could be assem value "Far", den value=0.3333 under column DRY, and WET column = NA.

Comment: I don't need to you to create the desired output in R, just typing a few rows by hand would be good. (And it's good incentive to make your sample input *minimal* so it's not too long to type out the desired output!)

Comment: However, it sounds like you don't really want to "reshape" your data, which would usually mean reducing rows by converting them into columns. It sounds to me like you want the same number of rows, maybe something like `df |> mutate(DRY = ifelse(Season == "DRY", den, NA), WET = ifelse(Season == "WET", den, NA))`, and perhaps dropping some of the old columns.